# stringByAppendingPathComponent Unavailable

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm updating my code for Swift 2, and I'm running into issues with my image file path that I have saved locally for a user profile. I'm not sure where to even fix this, I've tried with the URLByAppendPathComponent but I'm not sure what I'm missing

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
    })

    profileImageView.image = image

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] 

    var filePathToWrite = "\(paths)/profileImage.jpeg"

    var imageData : NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)!

    fileManager.createFileAtPath(filePathToWrite, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)

    let imageFile : PFFile = PFFile(name: "profileImage.jpeg", data: imageData)
    imageFile.save()

    let getImagePath = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("profileImage.jpeg")
    print("getImagepath: \(getImagePath)")

    let user = PFUser.currentUser()
    user.setObject(imageFile, forKey: "profileImage")
    user.saveEventually()
}
```

If anyone can help me figure out how to update my code here, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let nsPath = Path as! NSString
```

now NSPath has all the functionality you want - in swift2.0 they kinda disabled implicit casting even more

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had the same problem.. and i changed `.stringByAppendingPathComponent("profileImage.jpeg")` with `.stringByAppendingString("/profileImage.jpeg")`..

The thing that's importen here is the forwardslash `/`.

Answer (score -1):

Replace  this

```
var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
```

with

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
```